# Merge 2 arrays into same index value

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say i have the two following arrays

```
array_1 = ["Person One", "Person Two", "Person Three"]
array_2 = ["24", "25", "26"]
```

How would I merge these arrays together so that the output would be

```
["Person One 24", "Person Two 25", "Person Three 26"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
array_1.zip(array_2).map { |a| a.join(' ') }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this does work for a regular array, i misunderstood the construct of what i had `(Capybara::Element tag="td")`. but ill post a different question for that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it following way:

```
array_1.each_with_index.map{ |el, i| el + " " + array_2[i].to_s }
# => ["Person One 24", "Person Two 25", "person Three 26"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_1.zip(array_2).map { |a1, a2| "#{a1} #{a2}" }
#⇒ ["Person One 24", "Person Two 25", "Person Three 26"]
```