# Merging two arrays of Capybara elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, cucumber, capybara

This is similar to [something](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31386200/477037) I posted yesterday but i got mixed up with what I actually had in front of me. I have two arrays that need merging into the same index value but I have `capybara elements` as opposed to strings and integers.

Example

```
@returned_names = page.all('#results > table.result > tbody > tr.data:first-of-type > td')
@returned_yobs = page.all('#results > table.result > tbody > tr.data:nth-child(2) > td')

# Returns
@returned_names = [#<Capybara::Element tag="td">, #<Capybara::Element tag="td">, #<Capybara::Element tag="td">]
@returned_yobs = [#<Capybara::Element tag="td">, #<Capybara::Element tag="td">, #<Capybara::Element tag="td">]
```

So based on yesterday's answer to merge these together, matching index values I should do

```
@collection = @returned_names.zip(@returned_yobs).map { |r| r.join(' ') }
# Returns
["#<Capybara::Node::Element:0x000000038c50e8> #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x000000036fadf8>",
 "#<Capybara::Node::Element:0x000000038c50c0> #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x000000036fadd0>",
 "#<Capybara::Node::Element:0x000000038c5020> #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x000000036fada8>"]
```

Which so far looks like it's doing the right thing. I need to then convert this to an array of its text values, but when I do

```
@collection.map { |t| t.text }
```

I get an error

```
undefined method `text' for #<String:0x00000001938310>
```

I'm guessing I can't map from here as I don't have an enumerable object at this stage?

Is there a way to get `@collection` back to an enumerable object so that I can then map the text values ?

Answer (score 1):

`Array#join` converts each object (i.e. node) to a string. This should work:

```
@returned_names.zip(@returned_yobs).map { |name, yob| "#{name.text} #{yob.text}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
@collection.each { |capybara_element| }.map(&:text)
```

or more verbose but would do the same thing:

```
@text_collection = []
@collection.each do |element|
  @text_collection.push(element.text)
end
```